# JDBCTemplate hangs

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I am using JDBCTemplate. For one particular query JDBCTemplate hangs after calling more than 3-4 times, sometimes after 15-20 attempts. I haven't found any bug in my code.

```
private String getXXX(String table)
{
    System.out.println("Test 1");
    final List<String> data = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(SELECT_TBL_NME,
                new Object[] { table }, String.class);
    System.out.println("Test 2");
    ret = data.size() > 0 ? data.get(0) : null;
    return ret;
}
```

Console hangs at "Test 1" without any error if the function is called more than 15 times or sometimes even after the 3rd or 4th call.

Comment: How do you define dataSource used by jdbcTemplate? Looks like it's stuck obtaining a connection to the database.

Comment: My class is extending JDBCDaoSupport and in my bean   <code><property name="dataSource" ref="DBMetaDataDS"/></Code>

Comment: If you run it from another thread than main, make sure that you correctly handle error logging. Because it might be, that your query just silently fails and you don't see expected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you aren't closing the connections.

```
final List data = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(SELECT_TBL_NME, new Object[] { table}, String.class);
```

The line above will never end because the JdbcTemplate is waiting to get a connection from your db.

So if your db cannot give you a connection your application is waiting, waiting, waiting and it does nothing with the time.

**possible fix:** Since you are using Spring, check that you aren't doing operation outside your `queryForList` method.

I had the same problem few months ago because I was calling the ResultSet.getMetaData() outside my `queryForList` method and that was't releasing/closing the connection.

Comment: Thanx for reply but i already converted all my JDBCtemplete calls to normal JDBC with proper connection closing mechanism  and deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Issue could be not in Java layer.

First of all try to check your:

1. DB - try to excecute the same query with using DB tool (Toad,
   sqlplus, SQL Developer etc.) and make sure that DB is working. Issue
   could be on you DB object (it can be locked by some other session).
2. Network - the same issue could be because of bad latency. Make sure that your network working well.
3. Try to test the same query with plain JDBC.

Comment: Thanx for reply infate  I am using Toad to connect with oracle 10g and there is no such problem at toad side.  I tried Simple JDBC and it works.But in my project and queries are getting fired using JDBCTemplete. So can't shift to plain JDBC.  I am still confused why it is not throwing any error in JDBCTemplte